# Changing Button State through Mouse Clicks on Tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick, mouseevent, tkcalendar

Is it possible to change the state of a button simply by clicking on a date in a tkcalendar?

For example, I created a button that changes the background color of a selected date and it disables once it's been clicked. However, I want to change the state of this button back to `NORMAL` when I select a different date on the calendar that has not had its background color changed. I included the relevant code of what I've been able to do so far (it's not much):

```
cal = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", weekendbackground="white", weekendforeground="black")
cal.pack(pady=20, fill="both", expand=True)
cal.tag_config("make_red", background="red")
json_dict: dict[str] = {}


def turn_red():
    selected_date = cal.selection_get()
    cal.calevent_create(selected_date, "", tags=["make_red"])

    marked_date = cal.get_date()
    json_dict[marked_date] = "make_red"
    data_file = open("save_cal.json", "w")
    json.dump(json_dict, data_file)
    data_file.close()

    turn_red_button["state"] = DISABLED


turn_red_button = Button(root, text="Turn red", command=turn_red)
turn_red_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=60, pady=20)
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us? Remember: It's much harder to help if we don't know what you've already tried!

Comment: @JRiggles I just edited it to include my relevant code. I haven't really been able to do much regarding my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the virtual event `<<CalendarSelected>>` to a function and enable or disable the button based on whether event is created on the selected date:

```py
def check_date(event):
    selected_date = cal.selection_get()
    turn_red_button["state"] = DISABLED if cal.get_calevents(date=selected_date) else NORMAL

cal.bind('<<CalendarSelected>>', check_date)
```